# In an one to many association, what's the difference between Model.new and models.new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models, Cart, CartItem, Product. In each them I defined association like this:

**cart.rb**

```
has_many :cart_items
has_many :products, through: :cart_items, source: :product

def add_product_to_cart(product)
  ci = cart_items.new
  ci.product = product
  ci.quantity = 1
  ci.save
end
```

**cart_item.rb**

```
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to :product
```

---

here's the related columns of cart_item, **db/schema.rb**

```
create_table "cart_items", force: :cascade do |t|

   t.integer  "cart_id"
   t.integer  "product_id"
   t.integer  "number",     default: 1
   .
   .
   .

end
```

---

**Then I did this in console:**

```
>> p = Product.first
>> c = Cart.create
>> c.add_product_to_cart(p)
>> CartItem.last
```

**My question is:**

In cart.rb the first line of add_product_to_cart(product)

When I use `ci = cart_items.new` , it works ok, the new cart_item has a **:cart_id = 2**

But when I use `ci = CartItem.new` , the new cart_item's **:cart_id => nil** ,this time the cart_item didn't get a cart_id.

Why this happens?  In controller.rb, the `new` method seems to follow a capital Class_name.

What's the difference?  When should I use `cart_items.new` and when should I use `CartItem.new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know about `models.new`, but I can verify that it works. It's an alias for build, as you can see here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L292

I think Rails is being confusingly convenient here, since I have never ever seen an instance method implementation of `new`, which is why I initially thought it was a writing error on your part.

For me, `new` borders a reserved word for constructing instances of classes.

So what am I saying?

In Ruby, there is no reserved keyword for instantiating classes like in say Java, where you write `new CartItem()` to build an instance. Instead, all classes provide a (class/static) method called `new`, which will build a new object and invoke the `initialize` instance method from the class to set up the instance.

The reason why `ci = CartItem.new` does not work as intended, is because you initializing a new instance of CartItem without any context. The fact that you calling it from inside `cart.rb` doesn't matter at all. There is no way to infer that you want this new CartItem to belong to a particular Cart record.

When you call `cart.cart_items` you get a peculiar object called an ActiveRecord Association Collection Proxy which is not an entity on it's own, but rather an object that carries the necessary context for invoking the next method in the chain.

This object knows your context is CartItems and it knows it has been built in the context of a specific Cart, in your case, the cart_id of 2.

When you call `build` on the collection proxy, like

```
my_new_cart_item = cart.cart_items.build
```

it will automatically set the cart_id of the new cart item instance to the id of the cart it was built from.

Alternatively, you could have called CartItem.new(cart_id: 2) to obtain the same result.

So in conclusion:

I think you should **never** use `cart_items.new`, as it's anti ruby convention and should really just throw a NoMethodError. It seems like a brainfart by the Rails team to merge it in, but when Rails was young a lot of clever stuff was added for convenience. I suggest that you use `cart_items.build`, which does the same thing, but is clearly recognisable by other rails developers.

Use `cart_items.build` when you want to build a new instance that should belong to an existing cart. Use `CartItem.new` when you would like to build a CartItem without setting it to belong to a particular cart.

In this case, it sounds like the latter doesn't make much sense, as a cart item without a cart isn't really a thing. But if you imagine that you have a Car and a Car has many wheels, then it may make sense to have a wheel which doesn't belong to a particular car (yet), because it may just be stocked in the inventory.

Comment: Thank you Niels. Very clear! I love your anwser.  And I tended to write `cart_items.new` , but I used `build`, sorry for that mistake. As you said, it's an alias.

Comment: I tried this: adding `ci.cart_id = self.id` under `ci = CartItem.new` . Then I tested it in console, it works too.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `.create` method on an ActiveRecord object, you are starting the object from scratch, implementing it, and saving it all in one step. Since it is being saved, it will enter the database and be assigned a `:cart_id`. If you have validations in your model for your AR object, you will see that calling the `.create` method will fail if you don't pass those validations.

Alternatively, calling the `.new` method on an AR object will only start the object, allowing you to implement it how you see fit before you have to specifically call the `.save` method on that object. Until you call `.save`, you haven't actually created anything that would be inserted into the database, therefore your `:cart_id` will be `nil`.

Go into the console and try different methods, including `.create` on one object and `.new` and `.save` on a separate object.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Dithanial. I 'll try it. :)

Comment: Okay. You also shouldn't initialize an AR object with an id; Rails will do that for you, and will do it better. As mentioned in the other answer, you also should not try to make a database entry by the table name, rather use the model it's attached to.